# is it possible to add a modify a bundle classloader to add another bundles classloader in osgi

Tags: java, osgi

I have a usecase where I need to dynamically load classes from different bundles in an OSGI runtime. I cannot export the packages as the other bundles could have duplicate classes and packages. However, the relation between bundles will be available. So, I need to modify a bundles classloader dynamically by adding other bundle classloaders to the parent bundle classloader.

Fragment bundles have this capability, but since fragment bundles cannot have multiple hosts, that option is ruled out.